# How to set up constructor function

Tags: javascript, object

Bit of a weird question how would you go about setting up a constructor function that would be called like this:

```js
let name = {name:'hi'};
name.log() 
// the log() function would log out to the console name.
```

I have been trying to rap my head around how to do this but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Add `log` as a property of the object.

```js
let name = {
  name: 'hi',
  log: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
name.log();
```

Comment: That's kinda what I'm looking for but I'm making a framework, and I would like it so you could pass any variable in as the name.

Comment: Then you should be using a class or prototype function, not an object literal.

Comment: Sorry, but can you give a example of what you mean.

Comment: Read a tutorial on object-oriented programming in JavaScript.